# c# website login via WebBrowser Control and navigate to another page

Tags: c#, html, winforms, httprequest, webbrowser-control

I want to log in to a web page using `Winforms` and `WebBrowser` control. After log in I want to navigate to another page. I can successfully log in but after that I don't know how to navigate to desired page. The page I get after login has a dropdown menu and I want to navigate to one item in that dropdown list.

Page inspection of that element gives me something like this:

```
<a href="/tn/Dispatcher?reqkey=HTCRTIl0XDzcKP&amp;TARGET=file_upload">
    Text</a>
```

`reqkey` is every time automatically generated. I can't simply say `WebBrowser.Navigate(URL)` because I get an error. And I also don't know how to get `reqkey` and how to pass it.

This is my code for login:

```
  class Caller {
    private string _URL;
    private string _id;
    private string _nid;
    private string _pin;

    public Caller() {
    }

    public void SetParams(string URL, string id, string nid, string pin) {
        this._URL = URL;
        this._tid = id;
        this._benid = nid;
        this._pin = pin;

    }

    public void CreateBrowser() {
        try {
            Form wbForm = new Form();
            wbForm.Text = "Form 1";
            WebBrowser wbControl = new WebBrowser();
            int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            wbControl.Height = height;
            wbControl.Width = width;
            wbForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            wbForm.Controls.Add(wbControl);
            wbControl.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
            wbControl.Navigate(_URL);

            wbForm.Show();

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void InputLoginData(WebBrowser wb) {
        try {
            var inputElements = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement i in inputElements) {

                if (i.GetAttribute("id").Equals("id")) {
                    i.InnerText = _tid;
                }

                if (i.GetAttribute("id").Equals("nid")) {
                    i.Focus();
                    i.InnerText = _nid;
                }

                if (i.GetAttribute("id").Equals("pin")) {
                    i.Focus();
                    i.InnerText = _pin;
                }
                if (i.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Login")) {
                    i.InvokeMember("click");
                }

            }


         } 

        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if ((sender as WebBrowser).ReadyState == System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
            InputLoginData(sender as WebBrowser);
        }
    }


}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can unregister the first event, then, in `InputLoginData()` before looping through the html elements, register another `DocumentCompleted()` event where you process the new page. You can do it with an in-line anonymous function. Defining a method to extract the link at this time is not possible. There's no way to know how this element can be singled out from others in the page (unless it's the only anchor with an href attribute).

Comment: problem solved..? or needs solution?